# Branch.io deeplinking not working on Ionic simulator

Tags: ionic-framework, branch.io

I have set up a branch.io account and am trying to deep link from website to ionic app. My app url is sampleapp://.

When I go to my webpage from the simulator, has_app on branch.init() is set to true, so it seems like it sees my app, but then doesn't open it.

If I create a normal href with sampleapp:// it will open the app.

Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it to work on simulator, but built it on xcode, put on my device and deep link is working.